# Ampersand in JSON/PHP in POST

Tags: php, jquery, json, post, escaping

I'm having a text field which is send via JSON and jQuery (wrapped with `.toJSON` function) to my server via AJAX and POST request. On PHP side I'm doing `json_decode` .

Everything works but if I put ampersand (&) inside it splits up the POST parameter so its incomplete on PHP side (at least what `var_dump($_POST)` is writing out).

Shouldn't the toJSON and json_decode do all the job (escaping)? I tried `encodeURIComponent`, `& to &amp;`, `& to \u0026` and it's not working.

What I'm doing wrong?

AJAX call

```
function execute() {
    this.setupUrl();
    return $.ajax({
        type: this.requestMethod,
        data: this.getDataParams(),
        url: this.url
    });
}

function getDataParams() {
    if(this.data != undefined) {
        if(this.requestMethod == 'POST' || this.requestMethod == 'PUT') {
            return "data=" + $.toJSON(this.data);
        } else if(this.requestMethod == 'GET') {
            return this.data;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you showed us your code.

Comment: Change `getDataParams()` to `function getDataParams () { return (this.data === undefined) ? null : 'data=' + encodeURIComponent($.toJSON(this.data)); }` and it should work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple: Use an object for `data` instead of a string.

E.g. change your function like this:

```
return {data: $.toJSON(this.data)};
```

This will work in any case, no matter if you are using POST or GET.

Comment: String concatenation is root of all evil, again :D Thanks. Will accept in few minutes.

Comment: this won't work, since it'll have: {data: {data: json}}. See my answer

Comment: That depends on what he wants. However, you should consider sending a pure JSON payload, i.e. `data: JSON.stringify(this.data)` and use `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))` in the PHP code.

Answer (score 3):

`&` should be encoded as `%26`. Find something that does so.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the "data" thing, as you already have it in execute()

```
if(this.requestMethod == 'POST' || this.requestMethod == 'PUT') {
                return $.toJSON(this.data);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wierd. PHP and JS work together many yaers. Couldn't expect that php cant decode what js coded. So i'll need a special function to handle this.

```
function damn_ampersand(str){
    return str.replace('&', '%26');
}
obj = {"ololo": damn_ampersand("atata & foobar")}
json = JSON.stringify(obj);
```